# Create Zip Archive in Intellij for Java Project with external dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can someone please provide a step by step process for the following:
A standalone java application (no maven, no gradle)
Contains src , main and test classes
Contains external dependencies like junit.jar etc..
How to create a zip archive of the same, so that I can ship to another machine and run it?

Comment: Is this for another developer to work on? is it for a user? why do you want the tests included?

Comment: for another user to work on.

Comment: I exported to eclipse and then created a zip archive, but thats not what I want to do in future..